# IPTables for packet routing with two wifi networks

Tags: iptables

We are currently setting up a system where we are using a Linux computer (debian) that acts as a WiFi control and router. The Linux computer connects to two WiFi networks (let's call them A and B) via WiFi (wlan0 and wlan1). A PC is then connected via ethernet to the Linux box to allow it access to any device on the two WiFi networks. See ASCII art image

```
                                             WiFi A (192.170.1.xx)
                                            /
                                           /
PC (192.168.2.xx) ----- (192.168.2.1) Linux (192.170.1.253) 
                                           \
                                            \
                                             WiFi B (192.170.1.xx)
```

Protocols that we need routed:

1. SSH to any 192.170.1.xx device from PC
2. TCP on ports 1234/4321 to any 192.170.1.xx device from PC
3. PING to any 192.170.1.xx device from PC

The question relates to how to setup the IPTables

- The PC has the gateway set to 192.168.2.1 so any packets that the PC sends to 192.170.1.xx will be routed to the Linux box?

This is what I think should work (not yet tested). Could you please indicate if this is correct or I have a fundamental mistake in my logic?

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan 1-m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Wifi A and B must be in different subnets otherwise the Linux system will complain.

I will assume that eth0 is for the PC, then you can use this rule to achieve what you want for the ssh and tcp ports:

```
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o <Interface> -d <Des subnet> -p tcp --dport <Des Port> -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

To allow ping you can use:

```
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o <Interface> -d <Des subnet> -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks this has worked. Would the TCP part also work for a TCP connection coming back from the WiFi devices?

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be using the same address range for Wifi A and WiFi B and the Linux box only has one address in that range I think you would need to bridge the two wlan interfaces (ie treat them as a single network) in which case your iptables rules would need to reference the bridge interface.
See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/607224/iptables-matching-packets-for-bridged-interface) for some ideas about configuring filtering on a bridged network.  Alternatively if you have assigned different subnets of 192.170.1.xx to each wifi network then the linux box will need 1 ip address on each subnet not the single 192.170.1.253 address you indicate.